# Restoring original version of script file in Python/Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I need help! My Spyder editor crashed. While restarting it asked me if I want to restore autosaved version of a file or restore the original one. I accidentaly clicked the 1st option and it turned out that autosave version was without any code becouse I accidentaly cutted it all out. Is there a way to get back my code?

I have no copies of the lost code and cannot think of any way to restore it.